# how to use jquery closest function

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, comments

i have made a webpage wherein i upload images to database n display them again from databse..while uploading the image i add comment to it in textarea,,and while displaying again the comment is shown and is editable too,now i have added a add comment textarea with display none and want to display it on clicking a button with jquery show function.
I am able to show(using jquery) the textarea(had display:none property)on clicking 'Add Comment' button but the problem is it always opens the textarea for the last uploaded image 
i read about using the closest property of jquery but its not working on my code,,i may be missing something i don't know 
This is my required css which wud b needed if u try runing the program..

```
    #commen{
        display:none;
    }
    #sq {
    background-image:url("wood.jpg");
        margin-top:1%;
       margin-left:30%;
       margin-right:20%;
       height: 70%;
        width:40%;
        float:left;}
```

Code where i display images and the comment input when uploaded,there's a add button which gives

```
        function displayimage()
    {
    <div id="sq">
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "databaseimage";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM images order by         image_id         DESC");

    while ($image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
    {
    echo '  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(         $image['url'] ).'" width="100%" height="100%">';
    $id=$image['image_id'];
    $sqlit = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM images_comments         where            comment_id='$id'");
         $image1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlit);  
         $text = $image1['text'];
    echo "<form method='post' action='page.php'>
         <textarea name='comment'          onblur=style.backgroundColor='darkgray'                 onclick=style.backgroundColor='white'>$text</textarea>
         <input type='hidden' name='imageID' value='$id'/>
         <input type='submit' name='submitComment' value='Submit'></form>";

         echo "<div id='commen'>
         <form method='POST' action='comm.php'>                           
         <textarea name='commentx'></textarea>            
         <input type='submit' name='Adcom' value='Add'>
         </form>   
         </div><a class='comment'>Add Comment</a>";
         echo nl2br("\n");
    }

    ?>
    </div>
```

my jquery function

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(e) {

     $('.comment').click(function(){    
     $('#commen').show();
     });
   });
   </script>
```

I just don't know how to use closest function.
Just need to know how to use closest fucntion properly here 
Any help is appreciated,Thanx...

I also have tried this code to show..

```
$('.comment').click(function(){    
$(this).prev().show();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you probably shouldn't have multiple elements with the same `id` on the same page. What you probably want in your JavaScript is

```
$('.comment').click(function(){    
    $(this).prev().show();
});
```

Comment: Thanx Chris for such a quick Rply...so u suggest I shud use js instead of jq? Is that right? And ny same id so u mean the div?

Comment: Also I have doubt that u haven't included commen div any where so on clicking add button when ur js function executes how wud the textarea in commen div will display? I have just started web programming so sorry for silly questions

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale JQuery is JavaScript. It's just a library that makes a lot of operations easier. I'd stick to using it if you find it useful. And yes, I mean there will be multiple divs with the id `commen`.

Comment: OK then I will add one more input with hidden type whhich will have my unique imageid, the same method I used to edit comment and it gives me no issues :P

Comment: I have doubt that u haven't included commen div any where so on clicking add button when ur js function executes how wud the textarea in commen div will display? Please explain   :(

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale The code I have provided finds the sibling element before the one that triggers the click event listener. In this case it happens to be your `div`.

Comment: Thanx sir..please can u provide me a link where I can I understand the concept about parent siblings ? Also I am gonna add a like button to every image, can u suggest an idea?Thanx again :)

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale [This page](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_siblings.asp) explains siblings. For adding a like button you probably should ask another question since there isn't really space to go in to detail in a small comment field.

Comment: its not working :( , i edited it in my js code and on running when clicked on Add Comment nothin happens,,help plz....

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale I just tried it and it works fine. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/xuk2nk46/3/

Comment: Sorry, there was a syntax error,,a last doubt Chris..eg,there are 4 images on a page,add comment works for every image the add comment button works,but if a click dat button for a image and then click add comment of another image,the prevous shown textarea should get hide again if its empty ....

Comment: Sorry, there was a syntax error and yes it works properly..a last doubt Chris..eg,there are 4 images on a page,add comment works for every image ,but if i click dat button for a image and then click add comment of another image,the previous shown textarea should get hide again if its empty("") ....

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale There's no space to put more code in the comments, so see my updated code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xuk2nk46/4/). If you need more help you probably should ask another question.

Comment: OK I got :) , u said div with same id shud b changed,so wat I can do for it?plz make changes in link u gave in above comment if possible ...

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale I already made that change. I changed the ID to a class.

Comment: ohh means same named class are not a problem,right?

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale Yes, you can have as many elements you want with the same class but IDs should be unique.

Comment: Thnx Chris :) if I have any other doubt, I'll post another question nd post d link  here for u To help me...

Comment: Chris i have added a cs3 feature and have problem implementing it in php,HELP!
Link:-    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556502/add-css-3-image-filters-to-php