# add css 3 image filters to php

Tags: php, html, css, imagefilter

I made a webpage where I upload (to a database) and display at same time in latest uploaded manner like any social networking.

I added a button "Add Filter", which on clicking opens a new page where I need to display the image associated with that corresponding button and radio buttons with different filter values. I am able to display the image and buttons properly but on clicking the filter buttons the effect does not apply.

First I tested the buttons on basic HTML and all worked perfectly. But when I tried in php, effect was not getting applied.  I know the reason for this, that is, I am not able to write proper syntax for div id #myImg, which in HTML we write as

```
<img id="myImg" src="cool1.jpg" />
```

But in php I am able to give id (I mean the position, etc, property is properly applied) but effects are not getting applied

Here's my code

```
  <html>
<head><title>Play </title>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Img Filtr</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/trystyle.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">


function click_position(obj)
{
change_position(obj.value)
}

function change_position(val)
{

    var s="demoDIV";        
        s="myImg ";
        s=s.trim();     
    document.getElementById(s).style.filter=val;        
        document.getElementById(s).style.WebkitFilter=val;      
var x="filter:<span id='enlargecssprop'>" + val + "</span>";
var y="img#myImg {<br>        ###CSSPROP###;<br>}<br>";
var z=y.replace("###CSSPROP###",x);     
}
</script>
<style> 
.playit {
    background-color:#ffffff;
  margin-top:1%;
   margin-left:55%;

float:left;     
font-family:Consolas,'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

    img#myImg {
    filter:none; 
    width:50%; 
    height:70%;
    line-height:200%; 
    margin-bottom:15%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px;
    left:0;
}   

</style></head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "databaseimage";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
 if(isset($_POST["filter"]))
 {

$image = $_POST['imageID']; 
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT url FROM images where      image_id='$image'");
$image = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

     $image1= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image['url']      ).'"  width="500" height="500" >';

 echo $image1;//how to add the myimg id to give effects
        echo "  <form class='playit' action='javascript:return false;'>
            Filter:<br><br>
            <input type='hidden' id='preselectedValue' value='none' />

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_1' value='none'/><label for='value_1'>none</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_2' value='none'/><label for='value_2'>blur(5px)</label></div>                

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_3' value='none'/><label for='value_3'>contrast(200%)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_4' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_4'>drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px red)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_5' value='none'/><label for='value_5'>grayscale(100%)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_6' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_6'>hue-rotate(90deg)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_7' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_7'>invert(100%)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_8' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_8'>opacity(30%)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_9' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_9'>saturate(8)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_10' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_10'>sepia(100%)</label></div>

                <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_11' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_11'>contrast(200%) brightness(150%)</label></div>

               <div class='radio'><input autocomplete='off' type='radio' name='radio_position' onclick=click_position(this) id='value_12' value='none'/><label for='value_1'><label for='value_12'>brightness(200%)</label></div>                   

            </form>";

 }
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I think I just need the proper syntax.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you've set the ID. Does changing:

```
$image1= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image['url']      ).'"  width="500" height="500" >';
```

to

```
$image1= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image['url']      ).'"  width="500" height="500" id="myImg" >';
```

work?

Comment: No, only the styling property gets applied on doing that, js fn doesn't work properly...

Comment: I also tried like dis echo "<div here>'<img tag>'</div>" dis also works in d same way that is only styling property is applied , I have read about imagefilter,etc inbuilt functions of php, if possible just give me an example for 2 effects on clicking button,,I'll implement rest ....

Comment: @ShubhamAmbavale The value of all your effects is set to "none" though, so surely nothing will happen unless you change that to an actual effect?

Comment: Omg , I forgot to change its values. How can I forget to changes dis :( -_- I'll see n Rply ,,, :)

Comment: @Chirs i have edited the question as that was my silly  mistake,now i am able to giv effects but also i want to store that into database on clicking the save button

Comment: My new Doubt(question)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641578/5-star-commenting-system-php